# How to concatenate int with str type in Jinja2 template?

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I want to set a variable in jinja2 template which is a combination of string and a interger value.

Code is as follows:

```
{% set the_var = 'Wan_Links.WAN_' + i + '.wan_link_type' %}
```

Here "i" is a dynamic value and is of type int. When I run the above code I get the below error:
**TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects**.

The expected output is **the_var = Wan_Links.WAN_0.wan_link_type** (i.e. i=0).
Can anyone tell me how can I get this done?

Answer (score 34):

You can also use the `~` Operator:

> `~` Converts all operands into strings and concatenates them.
>   `{{ "Hello " ~ name ~ "!" }}` would return (assuming name is set to 'John'):
>    `Hello John!`.

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/

Answer (score 23):

Got in done by adding "String" to it.
Correct syntax is:

```
{% set the_var = 'Wan_Links.WAN_' + i|string + '.wan_link_type' %}
```